# How to hide bottom Widgets while scrolling using bloc

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to hide `Floating Action button` while scrolling using `bloc` but didn't work..

This is the below `bloc` class :

```
class AppCubit extends Cubit<AppStates> {
  AppCubit() : super(AppInitialState());

  static AppCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

  int currentIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> screens = [
    FeedsScreen(),
    ChatsScreen(),
    UsersScreen(),
    SettingsScreen(),
  ];

  List<String> titles = [
    'Home',
    'Chats',
    'Users',
    'Settings',
  ];

  ScrollController scrollController =
      ScrollController(); // set controller on scrolling
  bool show = true;

  void hideBottomWidget() {
    show = false;
  }

  void showBottomWidget() {
    show = true;
  }

  void handleScroll() async {
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        hideBottomWidget();
      }
      if (scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.forward) {
        showBottomWidget();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and this is the below Layout Screen I have :

```
class SocialLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const SocialLayout({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        var cubit = AppCubit.get(context);
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              cubit.titles[cubit.currentIndex],
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(IconBroken.Notification),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(IconBroken.Search),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: cubit.screens[cubit.currentIndex],
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: cubit.currentIndex,
            onTap: (index) {
              cubit.changeBottomNavIndex(index);
            },
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Home), label: 'Home'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Chat), label: 'Chat'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Location), label: 'Location'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(IconBroken.Setting), label: 'Settings'),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          floatingActionButton: Visibility(
            visible: cubit.show,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () { },
              tooltip: 'Post',
              child: Icon(IconBroken.Paper_Upload, color: Colors.white,),
              elevation: 2.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

here I wrapped with the `visibility` widget and add the `visible` state..

The below code the screen which contains the `ListView.separated()`:

```
class FeedsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FeedsScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var responsive = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        var cubit = AppCubit.get(context);
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Card(...),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              ListView.separated(
                controller: cubit.scrollController,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildPostItem(context),
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10,),
                itemCount: 10,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildPostItem(context) => Card(....);,
      );
}
```

as you see I called the `controller: cubit.scrollController,` in the `ListView`

and this is below main I have which I called the `handleScroll` method in the `BlocProvider()` as the below code:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
  DioHelper.init();
  await CacheHelper.init();

  Widget widget;

  uId = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'uId');

  if (uId != null) {
    widget = SocialLayout();
  } else {
    widget = LoginScreen();
  }

  runApp(MyApp(
    startWidget: widget,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget startWidget;

  MyApp({
    this.startWidget,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AppCubit()..getUserData()..handleScroll(),
      child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: lightTheme,
            themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
            home: startWidget,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution, I for get to add the emit in the below methods and just add the emit there as the below code:

```
  void hideBottomWidget() {
    show = false;
    emit(AppHideBottomWidgetState());
  }

  void showBottomWidget() {
    show = true;
    emit(AppShowBottomWidgetState());
  }

  void handleScroll() async {
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        hideBottomWidget();
        emit(AppHandleReverseHideBottomWidgetState());
      }
      if (scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.forward) {
        showBottomWidget();
        emit(AppHandleForwardHideBottomWidgetState());
      }
    });
  }
```